# CRUD Laravel with QueryBuilder can´t show in edit view

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

*(If necessary, translate from Spanish to English)*

I have a table with multiple relationship, the table "reservas" have 1 relationship with 3 tables, but that tables have other relationships.

I'll explain it:

Table "Reservas" have a relationship with the table "Doctor", table "Tipo_Consulta" and table "Clientes".

The other tables and their relationships are explained through the following SQL query.

```
SELECT id_consulta AS 'ID CITA', CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS 'MEDICO', area_salud.nombre_area AS 'TIPO CONSULTA', fecha_consulta AS 'FECHA', hora_consulta AS 'HORARIO', CONCAT(clientes.nombre,' ',clientes.apellidos) AS 'PACIENTES', sala AS 'SALA',estado_reserva AS 'ESTADO DE LA RESERVA' 
FROM reservas 
INNER JOIN tipo_consulta ON reservas.tipo_consulta_id = tipo_consulta.id_tipo_consulta 
INNER JOIN area_salud ON tipo_consulta.area_medicina = area_salud.id_area 
INNER JOIN medicos ON reservas.doctor_id = medicos.id_doctor 
INNER JOIN clientes ON reservas.paciente_id = clientes.id_paciente 
ORDER BY id_consulta ASC;
```

[image]

"Reservas" is the main table of this query. I using the same SQL Query in LARAVEL with QueryBuilder. **Is more easy for me**. I want to edit a row, using relationship that is the reason that I do not edit only the table "reservas" without using table relations.

I think my code isn't right. I receive null value and the view show me the following error.

[image]

**I'll try to show the values from the selected row**, I have a previous table that show all rows from the table "reservas". The following code is from the **edit-view**.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('UpdateCitas', $reservas->id_consulta)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <x-input-label for="MedicoActual" :value="__('Medico a cargo')" style="font-size: 16px;"/>                                         
        <input type="text" name="MedicoActual" value="{{$cita->nombre_doctor}}" class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Doctor's name">                                                         
                                
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="ACTUALIZAR">
  </div>
</form>
```

I don't need to use `@foreach`, I think is not necessary, but I don't understand what I can do.

Now I will show the line of code that gives me a null value.
Is from the controller the edit function.

```
public function edit(Reservas $reservas){

    $cita = DB::table('reservas')
    ->join('tipo_consulta', 'reservas.tipo_consulta_id', '=', 'tipo_consulta.id_tipo_consulta')
    ->join('area_salud', 'tipo_consulta.area_medicina','=','area_salud.id_area')
    ->join('medicos','reservas.doctor_id','=','medicos.id_doctor')
    ->join('clientes','reservas.paciente_id','=','clientes.id_paciente')
    ->selectRaw("CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_doctor, id_consulta,nombre_area, valor_consulta,fecha_consulta,hora_consulta,clientes.nombre,clientes.apellidos,sala,estado_reserva")
    ->where('reservas.id_consulta', '=', $reservas)->get();
    
    return view('forms.editar-citas', compact('cita', 'reservas'));

}
```

The variable `$reservas` must be the `id` from the table "reservas", the id called `id_consulta`, but is null, the url have the correct id number. What can I do?

Remember, now I trying to show the Doctor's name value in the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() method will return a collection. If you want to retrieve a record, use first() method instead

```
public function edit(Reservas $reservas){

    $cita = DB::table('reservas')
    ->join('tipo_consulta', 'reservas.tipo_consulta_id', '=', 'tipo_consulta.id_tipo_consulta')
    ->join('area_salud', 'tipo_consulta.area_medicina','=','area_salud.id_area')
    ->join('medicos','reservas.doctor_id','=','medicos.id_doctor')
    ->join('clientes','reservas.paciente_id','=','clientes.id_paciente')
    ->selectRaw("CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_doctor, id_consulta,nombre_area, valor_consulta,fecha_consulta,hora_consulta,clientes.nombre,clientes.apellidos,sala,estado_reserva")
    ->where('reservas.id_consulta', '=', $reservas-> id_consulta)->first();
    
    return view('forms.editar-citas', compact('cita', 'reservas'));

}
```

You should check $cita to see if it is null

```
 <input type="text" name="MedicoActual" value="{{$cita ? $cita->nombre_doctor : ''}}" class="form-control" 
          placeholder="Doctor's name">
```

Comment: Thanks!! But, now I got another error and it's says: **Attempt to read property "nombre_doctor" on null**. I said the variable ```$reservas``` have null value.

Comment: Yes, because  $cita is null. Make sure it exists in the database

Comment: I had already explained that this code line -> ```public function edit(Reservas $reservas)``` in the controller, must have the ```id``` value from the table Reservas according the prevoius selected record from a table in the view, ```$cita``` is a local variable whose purpose is to display the values of the sql query according to the selected record from a previous table (in the view). For example if ```$reservas``` have a value 4, then the Query should show a especific result. And the following code line should be ```where('reservas.id_consulta', '=', 4)->first();```.  That's what I'm trying.

Comment: Are you available?
I still can't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should be ->where('reservas.id_consulta', '=', $reservas-> id_consulta

Comment: First of all, I had to take an extra step to find a solution. I edited my route: ```Route::get('/citas/editar/',[ReservasController::class, 'edit'])->name('reservas.edit');``` to this: ```Route::get('/citas/editar/{reservas}',[ReservasController::class, 'edit'])->name('reservas.edit');```. And now it works! But your answer gave me an idea, thanks!